# CSS is not formatting my message properly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, hta

```
<body>

 <p class="tagged">****   Tutorials & Help Videos ****</p> 
 <p class="itmeggage">I have installed an icon on your desktop.
    <br><br> The icon is called 
    <span class="folders">eCats & HELP Videos</span>
    <br><br>
 </p>
 <p class="itmessage">There are two folders.
    <ol>
        <li>CheatSheet</li>
        <li>Help Videos</li>
    </ol>
 </p>
    <br><br> 
 <p class="note">NOTE: Help Desk is expected to go live Thursday evening or Friday morning.</p>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: lightblue; }

  p.tagged {    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: red;
    text-align:center;
  }
  p.itmeggage {    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;        
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */ 
    width: 500px; /* change to your preferences */ 
    white-space: wrap; /* paragraph to one line */ 
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */ 
    text-align:left;
    color: green;
  }
  span.folders {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: purple;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */ 
    width: 500px; /* change to your preferences */ 
    white-space: wrap; /* paragraph to one line */ 
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */ 
    text-align:left;  
  }
  p.note {    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    color: black;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */ 
    width: 500px; /* change to your preferences */ 
    white-space: wrap; /* paragraph to one line */ 
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */ 
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:underline;
  }
  li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: green;    
    white-space: wrap; /* paragraph to one line */ 
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */ 
    text-align:left;
    }

  </style>
```

The words "There are two folders" are not styling according to the CSS that i created. I don't know what to do.

Please help!

Comment: You misspelled `itmessage` as `itmeggage`.

Comment: put it as an answer and i'll give you credit

Comment: @CocoaDev Also note that you spelled it as "itmeggage" _twice._

Comment: Already had it as an answer. :)

Comment: Yup and I gave you credit :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `itmessage` as `itmeggage`:

```
p.itmeggage {    
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    ...
}
```

Also, your first `<p>` has the same spelling, which is why one worked, and the other didn't:

```
<p class="itmeggage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you had spelt the CSS selector wrong. It happens to us all :-)

Should be 'p.itmessage' instead of 'p.itmeggage'

```
  p.itmessage{    
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: x-large;        
text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */ 
width: 500px; /* change to your preferences */ 
white-space: wrap; /* paragraph to one line */ 
overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */ 
text-align:left;
color: green;
}
```